# mysql update value if another one is not null

Tags: mysql, sql-update, isnull

what's wrong with this query?

```
UPDATE `order` SET `total_no_vat` = IF(`total` IS NULL,NULL,(`total`/(1.10)));
```

I get an error that I cannot interpret:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') )' at line 1

any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
UPDATE `order` SET `total_no_vat` = `total`/(1.10);
```

If `total` is `NULL` then `total/(1.10)` evaluates to `NULL`.